# Is there anyway I can make the output easier to read, Reading Data from 1000+ JSON files

Tags: python, json

**My code**

```
import os
import json
path_to_json = './validatedto'
json_files = [file for file in os.listdir(path_to_json) if file.endswith('.json')]
json_data = []
for index, data in enumerate(json_files):
    f = '{0}/{1}'.format(path_to_json,data)
    with open(f) as file:
        d = json.loads(file.read())
        print(d)
        json_data.append(d)
output_path = os.path.join('.','output.json')
with open (output_path, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(json_data, f)
```

**Output**

[image: output]

Comment: Define "easier to read". You may try `json.dump(..., indent=4)` for starters.

Comment: That Helped a lot, thank you

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pathlib.Path` instead of `os`

```
import json
import pprint
from pathlib import Path

base_path = Path('validatedto')
json_files = list(base_path.rglob('*.json'))
json_data = []
for index, path in enumerate(json_files):
    d = json.loads(path.read_text())
    pprint.pprint(d)
    json_data.append(d)

output_path = Path('.') / 'output.json'
output_path.write_text(json.dumps(json_data, indent=4))
```